# Bad order on embeded list annotated with @ElementCollection and @OrderColumn

Tags: java, jpa

Load parent and its children but order is NOT as on database.

There is Parent class with a list of embeddable Child, both annotated for JPA.

```
@Entity
class Parent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    @OrderColumn
    private List<Child> children;
}

@Embeddable
class Child {
    private String name;
}
```

Related tables are filled with test data set, as below. Please note that children_order is reversed. Also rows order matters.

```
+----+--------+    +----+-----------+----------------+---------+
| id | name   |    | id | parent_id | children_order | name    |
+----+--------+    +----+-----------+----------------+---------+
| 1  | parent |    | 1  | 1         | 1              | child 0 |
+----+--------+    +----+-----------+----------------+---------+
                   | 2  | 1         | 0              | child 1 |
                   +----+-----------+----------------+---------+
```

Here is JUnit test case. EntityManagerFactory factory is initialized on @BeforeClass and test data set is loaded on @Before.

```
em = factory.createEntityManager();
String jpql = "select p.children from Parent p where p.id=:id";
List<Child> children = em.createQuery(jpql, Child.class)
                         .setParameter("id", 1)
                         .getSingleResult();
em.close();

assertThat(children.get(0).name, equalTo("child 1"));
assertThat(children.get(1).name, equalTo("child 0"));
```

Test case is failing an I have no clue why. For sure I do something wrong but I do not know what. I did search on Internet and of course SO but no luck. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess here is that it works as it should work. You are fetching the list of children using JPQL query. I don't think in this case `@OrderColumn` will work. It shouldn't, because it's not being used in this case.

If you want it to work, you need to fetch `Parent` record instead. Let's say you can find it by ID (example):

```
Parent parent = findById(1);
```

Now you can get a list of children from the parent:

```
List<Child> children = parent.getChildren();
```

and only when you get `children` like this, you should expect your result list to be ordered.

Happy Hacking :)

Comment: Hi Sir. Thank you for your reply. I have SQL log active and I see `children_order` column is retrieved and I supposed it is used for list ordering. Here is relevant log record: ```SELECT t0.NAME, t0.children_ORDER FROM PARENT t1 LEFT OUTER JOIN Parent_CHILDREN t0 ON (t0.Parent_ID = t1.ID) WHERE (t1.ID = ?)```. Anyway, your suggested is working and does solve my problem. Thank you again. Searching for a way to accept the answer. I am new on SO.

Comment: Accordingly Java Persistence 2.2, section 4.8.4 - Embeddables in the Query Result, embeddables returned by JPA queries are not managed, even if inside a managed persistent context. This is why returned children list from `select p.children from Parent ...` has no order processed.

On the other hand, when execute `select p from Parent ...`, embeddables children are part of a managed entity, the Parent entity. Therefore become managed too and order is processed.